# Make a date-like html input field in React (auto separate numbers with dots)

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, date, input

I want to make an input field that would auto split any numbers while they are being input, like type="date" input field. The problem with date input that it turns into full calendar on mobile devices, while I need only putting numbers by hand. Maybe I can do this with React, or maybe there is an option in plain HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it with the checking in function in React.

It goes like this:

```
let val = event.target.value.trim()
    let name = event.target.name
    if(name === "birthDate" && (val.length === 2 || val.length === 5 ) && this.state.birthDate.slice(-1) === ".") {
        val = val.slice(0, -1)
    }
    if(name === "birthDate" && (val.length === 2 || val.length === 5 ) &&  this.state.birthDate.slice(-1) != ".") {
        val = val+'.'
    }
```